# Multiple substring from a string and place it in a array php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am having trouble get multiple substring from a string using PHP

For example:

```
$id= 'a:4:{i:0;s:4:"8345";i:1;s:4:"8344";i:2;s:4:"8343";i:3;s:4:"8329";}';
```

Now I want get the results as:

```
Array[0]=> 8345
Array[1]=> 8344
Array[2]=> 8343
Array[3]=> 8329
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use `unserialize` on `$id`.

Comment: Why don't you just unserialize()

Comment: `$result = unserialize($id)`

Answer (score 2):

Just unserialize the data

```
<?php

$id= unserialize('a:4:{i:0;s:4:"8345";i:1;s:4:"8344";i:2;s:4:"8343";i:3;s:4:"8329";}');

print_r($id);

?>
```

Comment: AWESOME..!!! thank you than you..

Comment: if it is working accept the answer

Comment: @Krist Just keep in mind the big red box in the php manual about unseralize.

Answer (score 1):

[unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)  takes a single serialized variable and converts it back into a PHP value

```
$id= 'a:4:{i:0;s:4:"8345";i:1;s:4:"8344";i:2;s:4:"8343";i:3;s:4:"8329";}';

print_r(unserialize($id));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$returnValue = unserialize($id);`
the result will be like

```
array (
0 => '8345',
1 => '8344',
2 => '8343',
3 => '8329',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
$id= 'a:4:{i:0;s:4:"8345";i:1;s:4:"8344";i:2;s:4:"8343";i:3;s:4:"8329";}';
preg_match_all("/\d{4}/", $id, $numbers);

var_dump($numbers);
```

Matches all four digit numbers.